# Password Reset Email Notification does not work in real server Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, email

I implemented password reset using email and it works fine in localhost, but it throws an error in real server.

Here is the error:

```
    Swift_TransportException
    Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): 
    php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

and here is .env file content:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=laravel

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mygmail@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried using this configuration, but still doesn't work.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**How to fix this issue?**

Comment: if you are using gmail smtp then  have you created app password ?

Comment: Yes, The process is completely working in localhost, but it throws the error in server

Comment: It seems like your config is not registration since i thinks the host is mailhog can you include your mail config file and if you are caching the env please run php artisan config:cache and to be sure it is the correct .env does less .env on the server output the correct?